# How many thrones are referenced in Revelation 3:21?

Tags: revelation, throne-of-god

**New International Version**

> To the one who is victorious, I will give
>   the right to sit with me on my throne, just as I was victorious and
>   sat down with my Father on his throne.

**New Living Translation**

> Those who are victorious will sit with me on my
>   throne, just as I was victorious and sat with my Father on his throne.

**English Standard Version**

> The one who conquers, I will grant him to sit
>   with me on my throne, as I also conquered and sat down with my Father
>   on his throne.

Jesus is saying the victorious will sit on his throne, yet he also says he was victorious and sat on the Father's throne.

So, are those thrones one and the same (i.e. The Fathers throne became Jesus' throne, the same throne we will sit on)? Or is there some order of succession here, wherein Jesus is now on the Father's throne, thereby leaving an empty throne for us to sit on?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking this excellent question.  I have always loved this verse, and so thinking about it is a joy.  You truly have a gift, as asking questions is the first qualification for a Bible teacher.

It certainly seems (from a literal reading<sup>1</sup>) to be multiple thrones.  Also, Revelation 4:4 speaks of "twenty-four thrones", mentioned again in ch.11. And [Matthew 19:28](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?qs_version=NKJV&quicksearch=thrones&begin=47&end=47) (and the parallel passage in Luke 22:30) adds further light on the subject:

> So Jesus said to them, “Assuredly I say to you, that in the regeneration, when the Son of Man sits on the throne of His glory, you who have followed Me will also sit on twelve thrones, judging the twelve tribes of Israel."

There are clearly many thrones in Heaven.

But, then we read in Isaiah (quoted again by Stephen in Acts 7):

> Heaven is My throne, And earth is My footstool. [[Is 66:1]](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2066:1&version=NKJV)

Does the Father need a physical throne?  I should think not, except that the Lord has sat down on that throne.

Complicating this even more, is the Lord's prayer in [John 17:21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%2017%3A21&version=NKJV):

> ... that they all may be one, as You, Father, are in Me, and I in You; that they also may be one in Us...

So in the truest sense, the Father has all heaven for a throne, and we will all be IN Him, when we are finally "one" and God is "all in all" [1Cor 15:28].

So are we agreed that there is one throne, two thrones, and many thrones, and that Heaven itself is a throne?

I really hope this doesn't just come across as cheeky.  I am not imagining that this is really an answer, for all of these things have symbolic meanings that even the best scholars of eschatology don't agree on.  But I doubt anyone can truly imagine what the throne (thrones) of Heaven will be like, let alone give a truly simple answer to this simple but wondrous question.

---

<sup>1</sup> I am not a literalist in the strict sense.

Answer (score -1):

There is only one throne of power. The Father reigns from it now until death is annihilated. Then Christ will give all rulership back to the Father. Then He Himself will be “elevated” back within the Godhead as it was before He came down as the the Son.

“Then cometh the end, when he shall have delivered up the kingdom to God, even the Father; when he shall have put down all rule and all authority and power. For he must reign, till he hath put all enemies under his feet.”
‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭15:24-25‬ ‭KJV‬‬

We as glorified sons and daughters of the most high will sit at the right hand of the Godhead.  Remember: the Godhead (Elohim) is the trunk or root of the tree, and we are the branches.

“For if the firstfruit be holy, the lump is also holy: and if the root be holy, so are the branches. And if some of the branches be broken off, and thou, being a wild olive tree, wert grafted in among them, and with them partakest of the root and fatness of the olive tree;”
‭‭Romans‬ ‭11:16-17‬ ‭KJV‬‬
http://bible.com/1/rom.11.16-17.kjv

There IS ONLY ONE TREE. ONE THRONE OF POWER. ONE GODHEAD.  ONE LORD.

“Hear, O Israel: The Lord our God is one Lord:”
‭‭Deuteronomy‬ ‭6:4‬ ‭KJV‬‬
http://bible.com/1/deu.6.4.kjv